# Swift: Double/Float is not getting decimal values

Tags: ios, iphone, swift5, xcode12

I'm trying to get the decimals in simple division but is always returning zero:

```
(lldb) po Double(20 / 100)
0.0

(lldb) po Float(20 / 100)
0.0
```

Any of you knows why is returning zero? or there is a way to get the of `0.20` ?

I'll really appreciate your help

Answer (score 5):

`20 / 100` is an integer division, and so is 0 (since 100 > 20). That 0 is passed to `Double.init`.

You want floating point division:

```
20.0/100.0
```

You can also use `20.0/100` since a Double divided by an Int is a Double, or `20/100.0` for the same reason.

None of these will return 0.20 exactly, since [that can't be represented by Double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken). `20.0/100` is 0.20000000000000001. But I assume this is what you're looking for.